# create serial numbers based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a following data

[image]

I want to create the Index Level as shown in last column based on Region, Country, Store Type and Location column. 
So Region column will have its own serial number for each new region i.e. 'APAC is 1 and then EMEA will be 2' similarly its same for other columns(Country, Store Type, Location). 
I have tried to use partition to get the result but i am not able to get desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dense_rank()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) window function.

```
select *,
       concat(
        dense_rank() over(order by Region), ',',
        dense_rank() over(partition by Region order by Country), ',',
        dense_rank() over(partition by Region, Country order by [Store Type]), ',',
        dense_rank() over(partition by Region, Country, [Store Type] order by Location)
       ) as [Index Level]
  from Tab
```

Answer (score 0):

You use simple CONCAT function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) or + operator to concatenate all the values together and divide all the values with comma.

Comment: No i am not asking concatenating values. I want to create those serial numbers based on hierarchy.